# Mysql query to fetch records which are not matched form both tables

Tags: mysql, join

I am new to here.
I have two two tables , one is temporary table and another one is main table.Before doing final process user click on refresh button . Then I am populating data into the temporary table and need to display to user if there is any difference between two tables like old value - new value. For this I tried below query but not able get the old value. I am getting as null

```
Temporay table

+------+--------------+----------------+-----+
| asn        |       ean |   belegnr |quantity|
+------+--------------+----------------+-----+
|  700000845 | 4046228201122| 30059314 |2  |
|  700000845 | 4046228138879| 30059314 |3  |
|  700000845 | 4046228138875| 30059320 |25 |
+------+--------------+----------------+--+--+
```

Main Table

```
+------+--------------+----------------+-----+
| asn        |       ean |   belegnr |quantity|
+------+--------------+----------------+-----+
|  700000845 | 4046228201122| 30059314 |5  |
|  700000845 | 4046228138879| 30059314 |3  |
|  700000845 | 4046228138888| 30059320 |25 |
+------+--------------+----------------+--+--+
```

From both tables I have change in ean field and in quantity field
For this I am using this query

```
SELECT
t2.id,t2.ean,t2.belegnr,t2.`quantity`,t1.`quantity`  FROM
temp_table  t2
LEFT OUTER JOIN details  t1 ON
t1.asn = t2.asn
AND t1.ean = t2.ean
AND t1.belegnr =  t2.belegnr
AND t1.quantity = t2.quantity
WHERE t2.asn = 700000845
AND t2.`belegnr` in(30059314,30059320)
AND t1.id IS NULL
```

Below is the my expected result

```
+------+--------------+----------------+-----+---------------------- 
| asn        |       ean |    oldean|       belegnr |quantity|Oldqty|
+------+--------------+----------------+-----+----------------------|
|  700000845 | 4046228201122| 4046228201122 |30059314 |2  |   5     |
|  700000845 | 4046228138875| 4046228138888 |30059320 |25  |  25    |
+------+--------------+----------------+--+--+--------+-------------+
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is `asn` the `PRIMARY KEY` in each table?  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: asn is not primary key. asn is the common value in both tables.

Comment: In temporay table at the time when user click on refresh button then I am populating data from other source . After that the temp table data will be flushed.

Comment: From the above join I provided I am getting values like in screenshot. In place of old values I am getting null. http://prntscr.com/mh7ok9

Comment: If `asn` is not the PK, how do I know how to pair up the rows??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From both tables I have change in `ean` field and in `quantity` field

To solve *THIS* task you must use the next query:

```
SELECT t1.asn, t1.ean, t2.ean oldean, t1.belegnr, t1.quantity, t2.quantity Oldqty
FROM temp_table t1, details t2
WHERE t1.asn = t2.asn
  AND t1.belegnr = t2.belegnr
  AND (    t1.ean != t2.ean
        OR t1.quantity != t2.quantity )
```

**BUT...**

Looking at your example data and desured result I see that you want to get the record pairs when `ean` **OR** `quantity` is changed.

You can obtain the shown result from shown source data using the next query:

```
SELECT t1.asn, t1.ean, t2.ean oldean, t1.belegnr, t1.quantity, t2.quantity Oldqty
FROM temp_table t1, details t2
WHERE t1.asn = t2.asn
  AND t1.belegnr = t2.belegnr
  AND (   (     t1.ean = t2.ean
            AND t1.quantity != t2.quantity )
       OR (     t1.ean != t2.ean
            AND t1.quantity = t2.quantity ))
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7cd71574b0e570a8ba78d5c1a0cb5095)

Comment: awesome, This is working like expected.. Thank  you very much man.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT asn
    FROM (
        SELECT * FROM temp_table
        UNION ALL
        SELECT * FROM details
         )
    GROUP BY asn, ean, belegnr, quantity
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 1;
```

should give you the `asn` values that have changed.  (Actually it will give 2 copies of them.)

```
SELECT a.asn,
       b.ean, c.ean AS oldean,
       b.belegnr, c.belegnr AS oldb,
       b.quantity, c.quantity AS old_quantity
    FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT asn FROM ( the-above-query ) AS x ) as a
    JOIN temp_table AS b  USING(asn)
    JOIN details    AS c  USING(asn)
```

should use that list of asns to find the rest of the columns.

(Provided by OP in a Comment:)

```
SELECT  a.asn, b.eannumber, c.eannumber AS oldean,b.quantity,
        c.quantity AS oldaty
    FROM  
    (
        SELECT  DISTINCT asn
            FROM  
            (
                SELECT  asn
                    FROM  
                    (
                        SELECT  *
                            FROM  temp_table
                            WHERE  asn =700000845
                              AND  belegnr IN (30059314,30059320)
                            UNION  ALL 
                        SELECT  *
                            FROM  details
                            WHERE  asn =700000845
                              AND  belegnr IN (30059314,30059320) 
                    )a
                    GROUP BY  asn, eannumber, belegnr, quantity
                    HAVING  COUNT(*) = 1
             ) AS X 
    ) AS a
    JOIN  dlnotes_refresh_temp_table AS b USING(asn)
    JOIN  desadv_details AS c USING(asn)
```

Comment: This is what I got - http://prntscr.com/mh7txj

Comment: @user3408779 - What did you get from the first `SELECT`?  I am assuming you match up the tables on just `asn`.  If that is wrong, then the first one needs to have more items, and the `USINGs` in the second needs more.

Comment: SELECT asn,eannumber, belegnr, quantity
    FROM (
        SELECT * FROM temp_table WHERE asn =700000845
        UNION ALL
        SELECT * FROM details  WHERE asn =700000845
         ) a
    GROUP BY asn, eannumber, belegnr, quantity
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 1

Comment: I got this result - http://prntscr.com/mh7v7g

Comment: The first pair of lines shows that eannumber changed; the second pair show that quantity changed.  That's what your desired result is, except for layout.

Comment: And this the full query - SELECT a.asn, b.eannumber, c.eannumber AS oldean,b.quantity,c.quantity AS oldaty
    FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT asn FROM ( SELECT asn
    FROM (
        SELECT * FROM temp_table WHERE asn =700000845 AND belegnr IN (30059314,30059320)
        UNION ALL
        SELECT * FROM details WHERE asn =700000845 AND belegnr IN (30059314,30059320)
         )a
    GROUP BY asn, eannumber, belegnr, quantity
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 1 ) AS X ) AS a
    JOIN dlnotes_refresh_temp_table AS b  USING(asn)
    JOIN desadv_details  AS c  USING(asn)

Comment: I changed the second select to get closer to your format.

Comment: @user3408779 - So are you happy now?

Comment: And, if it is not quite correct, can do you understand the steps (albeit rather lengthy steps) I took to get close to the answer?

Comment: Dear @Rick James, sorry, still not desired out put. This what exactly I need. In place of null I need old values . http://prntscr.com/mh7xj9

Comment: this is my main table - http://prntscr.com/mh82h6, this my temp table - http://prntscr.com/mh82ld  and my desired out put - http://prntscr.com/mh82pt  In place of null i need values from main table that is old values. Thanks you